# Can I log a VFR XC toward 141 commercial license while simulating instrument

Tags: contrails

I flew last night with a friend to split time. Half the flight I wore foggles, half the flight he did So we could both be PIC And both have approach/landing practice.  Could I log all of that simulated instrument time into a 141 VFR XC commercial flight lesson?

Comment: I would say that time spent navigating by reference to instruments alone does not meet the intent of VFR.  Can you give us an interpretation of 61.51 that supports your objective?  And does your school agree?

Answer (score 2):

Logging PIC/SIC time is straightforward.  Your scenario, commonly called “splitting time”, is widely accepted, as long as you scrupulously follow the rules in part 61.

Logging XC is a little more complicated; only a pilot who both takes off and lands for the same leg can do that.  That means *at most* one pilot can log XC time.

But being able to log time under 61 doesn’t automatically mean you can use that time as credit toward a 141 program. That depends entirely on the specific program syllabus approved by the FAA, so we can’t answer that here.  You’ll have to ask your CFI or maybe Chief Pilot to know for sure.